# System Sounds in Ubunto Studio 20.04 lts

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-studio

Where do I find them, that means where are the settings; how can I activate or change them?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the main menu (or CTRL+ESC) and go to Ubuntu Studio Controls.

Comment: This isn't very helpful. I just installed ubuntu studio 22.04 --- nowhere in the control panel is there an obvious way to change the alert sounds or mute them. There IS an option to mute a playback stream called "Notification Sounds" in the Audio controls, but, mine is set to mute and the computer is still playing alert sounds --- clearly this isn't it.